# GHDL: How do I bind components?

Tags: vhdl, xilinx-ise, ghdl

I'm running automated testbenches with ghdl (0.32rc1). Some of my testbenches require unisim primitives from Xilinx ISE.

I have prepared two [external files](https://gist.github.com/Paebbels/4dc8bd9918a82f042b2b), if one would like to test my example. To run my example, you'll need a Xilinx ISE or Vivado installation, so you can find the MUXCY primitive. It's located in the folder `<InstallDir>\ISE_DS\ISE\vhdl\src\unisims\primitive`.

I analyzed the three files with the following ghdl commands:

```
PS D:\Temp\ghdl> C:\Tools\GHDL\0.32RC1\bin\ghdl.exe -a --work=work C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\ISE\vhdl\src\unisims\primitive\MUXCY.vhd
PS D:\Temp\ghdl> C:\Tools\GHDL\0.32RC1\bin\ghdl.exe -a --work=poc .\arith_prefix_and.vhdl
PS D:\Temp\ghdl> C:\Tools\GHDL\0.32RC1\bin\ghdl.exe -a --work=test .\arith_prefix_and_tb.vhdl
.\arith_prefix_and_tb.vhdl:96:16:warning: universal integer bound must be numeric literal or attribute
```

So far no errors.
Now I started the simulation, which is just ghdl.exe -r on Windows (Linux: -e and -r):

```
PS D:\Temp\ghdl> C:\Tools\GHDL\0.32RC1\bin\ghdl.exe -r --work=test arith_prefix_and_tb
.\arith_prefix_and.vhdl:79:40:warning: 'mux' is not bound
.\arith_prefix_and.vhdl:43:14:warning: (in default configuration of arith_prefix_and(rtl))
```

Now ghdl reports that `mux` could not be bound.
I also tried the parameters `--syn-binding` and `-P.`, but nothing changed.

**What do I have to do to bind the MUXCY component?**

P.S. Can someone create a 'ghdl' tag? I don't have enough reputation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would fix this:

First, analyze the `MUXCY` in the unisim library as it is intended to be, like so:

```
ghdl -a --work=unisim C:\Xilinx\14.7\ISE_DS\ISE\vhdl\src\unisims\primitive\MUXCY.vhd
```

Note the `--work=unisim` in that command.

Then, make sure you add `library UNISIM;` at the top of your `arith_prefix_and.vhdl` file.

That should do it.

What I think is happening here is that, since you are overwriting the name of the `work` library to `poc` with the `--work=poc` when analyzing `arith_prefix_and.vhdl`, it does not see the the `MUXCY` entity analyzed in the actual library named `work`, and so it cannot find a default entity to which to bind the `MUXCY` component.

Comment: These files should slso compile for e.g. Altera which uses modelsim. You can try this by changing VENDOR to Altera. In that case a generic carrychain implementation is used. Because modelsim does not know unisim, I can't add a library reference to it. I know I could compile the Xilinx primitives for ModelSim but not every user of our library has XST or Vivado installed.

Comment: @Paebbels I see your point. What about creating an empty `UNISIM` library on systems without Vivado or ISE, is that acceptable for your use case? If VENDOR is set to Altera, you don't need anything in the library, you just need it to exist.

Comment: I consider this answer as a solution... (Waiting for further answers)